# Where is ticket data stored in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using awesome support plugin in wordpress for submitting tickets but I am not able to find out where exactly the ticket data is stored.

I have checked the wp_posts table in the wordpress database but have not found anything.

I have added some custom fields and I want to see how data is stored exactly as I want to use it for further processes.

Please let me know if anyone knows anything about this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That would be a question about the plugin and not WordPress itself, wouldn't it?

Comment: Check is there any other tables created for managing the tickets. Orelse it may be stored as json format in any of the Wordpress tables.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's stored in `wp_postmeta`. Try `var_dump(get_post_meta($post_id))`

Comment: We tried to find it inwp_postmeta, but we are not able to find anything related to the data in that table